# Database Errors while running dbt run

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am new to dbt and I am trying to run dbt from cli, which is connected to snowflake. I have successfully created a `profile.yml`, `dbt_profile.yml` and `dbt debug` shows everything is connected. but when I run `dbt run` to create the example models I get this error

```
  Running with dbt=1.0.1
  Found 2 models, 4 tests, 0 snapshots, 0 analyses, 179 macros, 0 operations, 0 seed files, 0 sources, 0 exposures, 0 metrics
Encountered an error:
Runtime Error
  Database error while listing schemas in database "LEE_Test"
  Database Error
    002043 (02000): SQL compilation error:
    Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.
```

Comment: Have you checked the log files in the log folder and the compiled code in the target folder? There you may find additional information about the error.

Comment: @MajaF. thanks alot for your response, it says SQL compilation error in the log, object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed

Comment: @MajaF. Please can I have a session with you on remotely.. This error is a blocker for me. Please. thanks

Comment: @lee The error suggests the issue is with the access to the particular object in Snowflake. Can you actually connect to Snowflake via UI and check the History for the SQL statement? If you have a query id and you can provide it I could have a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

okay there might be a  problems in your dbt profile in which u have given the snowflake detials there is some mistake there  probably in naming or either

here is an exmaple on how you can connect to snowflake

```
default:(profile name )
  outputs:

    dev: # User-Password config
      type: snowflake
      account: snowflake_account_link
      user: DBT_CLOUD_DEV
      password: *******
      role: your role of snowflake 
      database: your data base name
      warehouse: name of your warehouse
      schema: <your schema name >
      threads: 2
      client_session_keep_alive: False

  target: dev
```

let me know if this works or not